# Second look at my skipped suggested edit reviews to learn

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

I recently made it past the 2k reputation border on Stack Overflow and started to review suggested edits. In some cases I am not sure about whether an edit should be approved or rejected and thus I <kbd>Skip</kbd> the review.

Now I would like to see the outcome of the review, to be able to learn for future reviews, because there are several factors that allow to judge a review quite fairly:

- If the suggestion has been approved and at least two approvers have a high approval rate and almost no rejects the result could be a robo-approval.
- If the suggestion has been approved and at least two approvers have a balanced approval rate with a healthy amount of rejects the result is most likely a valid one.
- If the suggestion has been rejected the result is most likely a valid one.

Is there a simple possibility to "review" (in the meaning of "take a second look") suggested edits that have been skipped by myself?

If not, could that be added to the "review"-list on the "activity"-tab on the profile-page, maybe combined with a CheckBox so that listing the skipped reviews is optional?

**EDIT:** After reviewing some of my suggested edit reviews, I have a suggestion to add to this feature request. In the review overview on my profile page, I would like an option to see whether the final result of the review differed from my vote - because that are those reviews where I probably was wrong.

Answer (score 8):

Nice idea. If this feature is planned, I would like to implement the feature like this:

I skip a lot of reviews. So in my review list (if the feature is implemented) it will show a lot of reviews I skipped. So I suggest to add either a CheckBox (i.e. *Save this review*) or a Button like <kbd>Skip & Save</kbd> in the review page. So that system only store skipped review which is marked as *Save*.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a simple possibility to "review" (in the meaning of "take a second look") suggested edits that have been skipped by myself?

Yes. It is possible. I've done many times. The major condition for that is - TIME*. "When did you review it?" There are 2 ways to do that...

1) **Least effective way:** If you've skipped your review and within a minute, you think of reviewing it again, then you could go back using the browser "Back" button.

2) **This would work, only if lucky:** If you've enabled `Save history` in your web browser, then you could open the history, then click the post which you want to review again.

## For other reviews of yours...

Just open the history of reviews in suggested edits. For example, if you require that in SO, use https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history. It'll show all the history of your reviews. To open the post, click on `Edit` or `Approve` or `Reject` near to it (whatever you've given). It'll show the whole detail of reviews on the post (like which fella has approved / rejected)

---

<sup>*But, you can't review them some later time. Even in Physics.SE, the suggested edits queue is always empty (whenever I review). SO, Woah... More users and Techies, lot of mods, etc. you won't have the chance for re-reviewing..!</sup>

Comment: But (for the last option) history is not showing skipped review. And that's the request of the OP. :)

Comment: history shows what everyone has done. If you skipped it and others acted on it, you can look at it from history and see what they did.

Comment: Hi @KateGregory. By history, I meant "browser history" for #1 and #2. If he's lucky (by GMT), only one (or none) has reviewed it, he **can** do it of course ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The review history lacks the information I am looking for: The reviews I *skipped*. The browser history is an option, but I still would have to keep track of the reviews I skipped myself...

Comment: @Spontifixus: You're welcome. My reply was only to a part of your question. As it's a [tag:feature-request] too, my answer won't satisfy your lengthy question ;-)