# Add feature to save reviews in the review queue

Tags: feature-request, review

> **This is not the same as [Second look at my skipped suggested edit reviews to
>   learn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165442/second-look-at-my-skipped-suggested-edit-reviews-to-learn)**
>
> *– My suggestion focuses on adding a <kbd>Save</kbd> button to
>   allow the user to save a review they are not sure on, despite whether
>   they choose <kbd>Looks OK</kbd>, <kbd>Requires Editing</kbd>,
>   <kbd>Unsalvageable</kbd> or <kbd>Skip</kbd>.*

I sometimes review questions in the review queue and often I am unable to review questions due to them being out of my area of expertise. However, when questions are in my area of expertise, I sometimes become confused as to what to choose due to the state of the question. It would be extremely useful if a <kbd>Save</kbd> button was available, so that I can save the review and come back to it to see what everyone else marked the question as.

This would not only allow me to review questions I would not have been able to before, but also allows me to sharpen my current skills and review the questions I would normally review even better, as I am more aware of what other people choose and what I should choose.

**There could be an extra section on each user's profile, which keeps a record of each review item that they have saved, similar to this:**

[image: Saved reviews section]

---

**I have added a small, minimal demo to show what I mean:**

```css
html, body{ margin: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; } iframe { border: none; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

```html
<iframe src="https://n4qe3.csb.app/"></iframe>
```

**The demo is also available at [codesandbox](https://n4qe3.csb.app/).** *Remember that this is a minimal demo and lacks features; most of the links are also broken.*

Comment: You could always bookmark the review link and check back later.

Comment: I have a userscript that shows your reviews against your peers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251508/158100

Comment: @rene Thanks, that really helped.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Second look at my skipped suggested edit reviews to learn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165442/282094) and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222863/282094

Comment: @Rob The linked question suggests saving skipped reviews, whereas I am suggesting adding a save button to save reviews despite whether the user chooses skip or not, as stated in the top of my question.

Comment: Zera, your Q should be an A to one of my suggested dups (or another equal duplicate), on MSE a question ***is*** a "duplicate" if it **has the same** ***potential*** **answer**. For Reviews that you **have done** they *are* saved here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=reviews or Queue - My first suggested duplicate says: "... I would like an option to see whether the final result of the review differed from my vote ..." and the 2nd duplicate mentions: "... if I skip a review, is there a way to see how the next reviewer handled it?"; so your Q is an A there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature already kind of exists in the system, with the Skip button.

If you go to your review history in a particular queue by clicking the "history" tab in a particular queue (, clicking "my review history" if you're a 10k+ user reading this answer,) and checking the "show skipped reviews" box. Provided the review task hasn't since been completed by others or invalidated by later actions, you can access your skipped review task and make a review on it later.

I'll admit that this is a bit crude, and also mixes in posts that you actually intended to skip reviewing and not merely save for later. As TheLethalCoder commented, each review task has a unique link, which is preloaded into your URL bar when you make reviews. If you follow the same link, you can see the review task, as well as review it so long as it's not completed or invalidated. You can save this link and it will continue to work.